# Limits of FixedJoint in Unity

Tags: unity, joints

I've built towers of cubes where each cube is connected to the one before with a `FixedJoint`. At 30 high they flop about as expected, but at a certain point (demonstrated at 100 high) they explode and do something crazy, moving around at light speed.

Video: https://www.loom.com/share/8807d99f157c45a1899138b469b4dec3?from_recorder=1

Is there a limit to the amount of force/torque a `FixedJoint` can simulate properly? The forces are set to break at infinity.

Comment: It looks like you've demonstrated by example, the answer is yes. What do you need from us that your experiment does not tell you?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if that's the limitation of Unity or if it is possible what the correct setup to have a truly fixed joint is.

Comment: It's not a limitation of Unity, [it's a limitation of the discrete simulation used by game physics engines](https://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the). If you want two objects to be completely rigidly attached with no possibility for bending or error, make them a single rigidbody rather than using joints at all.

Comment: If you'd like help making a particular kind of construct in your game, you'll generally get better answers if you ask "How do I achieve [this specific thing]" - maybe joints or even physics simulation as a whole aren't the answer, and maybe the solution is something else entirely. It looks here like you're trying to build some kind of tower? Tell us about your game and the feature you're trying to build, and we can help you find ways to achieve it.